# Триггеры в игре. Название и реализация

Tags: c#, ооп, триггер, solid

Хочу добавить в игру триггеры, интерфейс типа ITrigger.

Вопрос первый: как правильно назвать этот интерфейс, если он может быть у: пилы которая убивает игрока, у блока на который можно встать и будет действие, у зоны в которую вошёл и будет событие.
Правильно ли понимаю что лучше всего подходит слово Trigger?

Вопрос второй, реализация. Как лучше реализовать универсально.

Сейчас например так:

```
    public interface ITrigger
    {

        void OnTrigger();

    }
```

Но это если без передачи параметра. А удобно было бы передавать того кто вызвал этот триггер.

Например так:

```
    public interface ITrigger<T>
    {

        void OnTrigger(T arg1);

    }
```

Вопрос в том на сколько правильно делать так, и на сколько оптимизировано ?

```
collider.GetComponent<ITrigger<Player>>().OnTrigger(this);
```

Пугает этот участок `ITrigger<Player>`, не идет ли кастование, распаковка?

Вопрос третий:
По мимо триггера обычного с одним методом, нужен триггер зоны / области, где будет вызов при входе и при выходе. Сейчас сделал так, но может можно лучше? По солид и ооп.

```
    public interface ITriggerArea
    {

        void OnTriggerAreaEnter();
        void OnTriggerAreaExit();

    }
```

Comment: Вы определитесь, вопрос "в общем" или конкретно про юнити, от этого многое зависит.

Comment: удалил тег юнити, что бы людям не было плохо

Comment: Людям не плохо, решение для юнити может отличаться от решения в вакууме.

Comment: Обобщения и были придуманы для избежания кастования и распаковки. А конкретнее по вашей проблеме трудно что-то конкретное сказать, т.к. не совсем ясны сценарии использования. У вас в голове они одни, а мы можем нафантазировать совсем иные. Нужны сценарии. Напишите тесты с моками и покажите их здесь, тогда можно будет понять о чем собственно речь.

Answer (score 0):

Реализовывать интерфейс не нужно. Столкновения обрабатывается [магическими методоми](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Collider.html) юнити. Для получения событий столкновения у обоих тел должен быть `Collider` и хотя-бы у одного `Rigidbody` которое двигается по физике (не ручным изменение `transform`).

Косаемо твёрдых тел (например пила)

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collider other) {
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

Косаемо тригеерных зон (`isTrigger` в компанентах типа `Collider`)

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.layer == 10) {
        // Коснулся триггера
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.layer == 10) {
        // Вышел из триггера
    }
}
```

Comment: Причем тут OnTriggerEnter и Unity )) Вопрос был абсолютно о другом. Об интерфейсах, триггерах их названии и реализации, а не о том что есть в юнити и чего нет. Увы вы не так поняли. Данный вопрос относится к ООП и Solid, про unity можно забыть

Comment: Указать тег `unity3d` не забыли. Тут порой люди спрашивают, как реализовать решение, которое им на самом деле не нужно.

Comment: Тем не менее обратите внимание на то как реализованы эти функции. У вас почему-то тип не определён `ITrigger<T>`, а у функцию юнити это `Collider`, что логично.

Comment: И `.GetComponent<...>()` в юнити принимает только классы наследованные от `Component`, не интерфейсы.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал воспользоваться [событиями](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-interface-events) и выстраивать пользовательские события относительно сабытий. Если события подвязаны то используем, если нет то идем дальше.

К примеру создал бы основной интерфейс, от которого буду наследовать абсолютно все ингорые элементы

```
public interface IGameObject
{
    string GetName();
    event EventHandler OnCreate;
}
```

Интерфейс пилы наследуем от `IGameObject`

```
public interface ISawObject : IGameObject{
    event EventHandler<IPlayer> OnCustomerInFireZone;
}
```

После чего можно уже переходить к реализации и выстариивать абстрации для упращения жизни

```
public abstract class AbstractGameObject : IGameObject
{
    private readonly string _name;

    protected AbstractGameObject(string name)
    {
        _name = name;

        OnCreate?.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public event EventHandler OnCreate;
}

public abstract class AbstractSawObject : AbstractGameObject, ISawObject
{
    protected AbstractSawObject(string name, int damage) : base(name)
    {
        _damage = damage;

        OnCreate += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Game object {GetName()} created");
        };

        OnCustomerInFireZone += (sender, customer) =>
        {
            if (customer.IsOnDistance(this))
            {
                // Что там происходит когда атакуют
            }
        };

    }

    private readonly int _damage;

    public override void Attack(IPlayer player)
    {
        OnCustomerInFireZone?.Invoke(this, player);
    }

    public int GetDamage()
    {
        return _damage;
    }

    public event EventHandler<IPlayer> OnCustomerInFireZone;

}
```